# Once I have a parameter that asks their name, how can I address them in each function without asking again?

Tags: python

I am writing a simple game in Python that contains multiple functions. I have a parameter that asks the user for their name. I would like to be able to address the user by name, within each of the functions, without asking for their name again.

I used an f-string within each function using the variable `{name}`, and I had hoped that the user name would show up in the text, but instead I got `<built_in_function_input>`, rather than the user's name. Below is the `greet()` function in which the name is asked:

```
def greet():
    name = input("what is you name?")
    
    print(f"hi there {name}") 
   
    answer = input("do you want to play a stupid game")
    if answer == "yes":
        print("ok, lets play!")
        select_showroom()
    if answer == "no":
        print("well your not missing anything!")
        exit()
```

then, as mentioned above, I used an f-string containing the variable `{name}` in each function to address the user by their name:

```
def select_showroom():
    name = input
    print(f"""{name} your in the lobby of the design building, three showrooms are open today.
          which one would you like to enter, 1, 2 or 3?""")
    choice = input("< ")
    
    if choice == "1":
        showroom1()
    elif choice == "2":
        showroom2()
    elif choice == "3":
        showroom3()
    else:
        print("try again")
```

Would I use a while loop?

Comment: read up on what [scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) mean in python

Comment: remove the line `name = input`  that's what is causing you the problem

Comment: also, with the line `name = input` you're not actually calling the function because you're missing `()` so it should be `name = input()`

Comment: also, and I'm being pedantic here, it's `you're` and not `your` in both usages

Comment: Do you mean to pass `name` as an argument to `select_showroom()` (i.e. `select_showroom(name)`/`def select_showroom(name): ...`)?

Comment: @EdoAkse ‘You name’ should be ‘your name’ in the first code block. I am also being pedantic :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short description of the scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: no but thank you-I decided not to put the variable into the global scope. Rather, I passed the argument of (name) into my select_showroom() function. Thank you for all the suggestions, much appreciated!

Comment: UpAndAdam, yes, thanks. It enlightened me in a different way that I can use in the future.

Answer (score 2):

First let's straighten up some terminology.  The variable isn't `{name}` it is `name`.  Variables have scopes.  See the link from Edo Akse for more on scopes.

A short summary of scoping is that unless a variable is declared in the global scope and is marked as `global` in a function before it is written to then the variable is limited to existence only in the function in which it's introduced.

This gives you two options

1. you can return and pass the user's name to each function as a parameter to the functions ( generally preferred )
2. you can make the user's name a global (not the worst thing in this case)

Currently none of the other functions know about the variable `name` because it is a local variable. However that must also be the name of a primitive function which is why the printout is saying what it is.  If you changed `name` to `user_name` for example I bet you would get a more clear error message that there is no such variable / that it is undefined.

Also see [Python global variable/scope confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439772/python-global-variable-scope-confusion)

Comment: yes, I see all that now, thanks so much!

Comment: if this answers your question it is suggested that you "accept" the answer